# Selection of multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select some hidden fields and loop over them. The fields look like:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="uitjes">    
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="form-0-Workshops">
    <input type="hidden" value="ochtend" name="form-0-Dagdeel">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-0-Aantal">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-0-Workshops">
    <input type="hidden" value="middag" name="form-0-Dagdeel">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-0-Aantal">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="form-0-Workshops">
    <input type="hidden" value="middag" name="form-0-Dagdeel">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-0-Aantal">
</form>
```

I select them like this:

```
var form = $("#uitjes");
form.find('input[name$="Workshops"]').each(rename);
form.find('input[name$="Dagdeel"]').each(rename);
form.find('input[name$="Aantal"]').each(rename);
```

The selection of Workshops counts in this case 3 elements:
`[input 1, input 1, input 3]`.

The problem is that all next elements counts one more element (4):
`[input#id_form-0-Dagdeel, input ochtend, input middag, input middag]`.

Therefore my loop works not as expected.

The selection of the first element is the preferred behavior. I am not getting why the first selection differs from the next ones.

The reason I am doing is to rename the fields to get an output like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="workshops">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="form-0-Workshops">
    <input type="hidden" value="ochtend" name="form-0-Dagdeel">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-0-Aantal">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-1-Workshops">
    <input type="hidden" value="middag" name="form-1-Dagdeel">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-1-Aantal">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="form-2-Workshops">
    <input type="hidden" value="middag" name="form-2-Dagdeel">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-2-Aantal">
```

Therefore I call this function (thanks to @epascarello):

```
function rename (i) {
    var parts = this.name.split("-");
    parts[1] = i;
    this.name = parts.join("-");
}
```

Comment: What is `input ochtend`?

Comment: Please specify, what input's you would like to select from your provided list.]

Comment: I will edit my post to clarify

Comment: i would suggest adding classes to your html input fields and find the input fields by those classes: `<input type="hidden" value="middag" name="form-0-Dagdeel" class="dagdeel">` and use `$('#uitjes').find('.dagdeel')` or simply `$('#uitjes .dagdeel');`

Comment: @MohammadAdil I want to select all inputs to do some formatting (see edited message)

Comment: Are you sure those are all of the inputs in the form? It appears that you have another element with `Dagdeel` in the name somewhere, and it's being selected.

Comment: @billyonecan There are some more inputs (hidden management inputs from Django formfactory) but not with the same name, also Aantal has the same problem

Comment: @joelharkes adding classes sound like a good solution, thanks +1 ! I am however still curious about why the selection from above isn't working....

Comment: Could you find the `input` which has the value `ochtend` and post it? I'm curious to know why it is getting selected

Comment: @billyonecan sorry for the confusion. The input fields are added dynamically, and I ran multiple tests. I copied between two test. I have edited my post to correct this issue. You were right that ochtend should not have been selected.